# Is there a way to parse HTML codes but parsed output doesn't changed?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Good day,

Here is my sample input HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Then after **Jsoup XmlParser**, here is the output:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta>
</meta>
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

**XmlParser** parsed the HTML codes without changing the arrangements
of HTML codes. But **XmlParser** put closing tag in every tag with no
closing tag as the **meta** tag in the example. I want to ask if there
is a way using Jsoup that can parse HTML code without adding or
changing anything from the source HTML code?

Please help, thanks

Comment: Why don't you want it inserting closing tags? This seems like an XY problem. [(What is the XY problem?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the html source is a `DOM Tree`. when `Jsoup` or other libs load html source, it will generate a `DOM Tree`. so it must has open and close tags to operate nodes.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps me to understand the parsing behavior of Jsoup.